# JetProductGallery обрезает изображение товара

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, elementor

[сайт](https://development.glamourbrideusa.com/product/wedding-hair-pins-3/) На данном сайте я реализовал индивидуальную карточку товара с помощью Elenentor Pro. Никак не могу решить проблему с слайдером галереи товара. Она должна показывать изображение товара, не выходя за границы блока (блок 600x600), но модуль, если изображение большое, обрезает её. Подскажите решение или плагин, который поможет. Я использую расширение для Elementor (JetProductGallery).

Comment: Когда ты уже научишься давать нормальные названия?

Comment: Если Вы используете платную версию JetProductGallery и это её причуды, рекомендую писать разработчикам, а для начала на их сайте посмотреть описание настроек.  По описанию совершенно не понятно о чём Вы пишите. Ну зашёл я на страницу и что? Должен гадать и фантазировать о какой области Вы пишите??? Скрины, выделение области о чём речь, это немного прояснит и сделает вопрос немного понятнее.